# Xcode Instruments not profiling anything

Tags: ios, profiling, instruments

I have just started out learning how to use Instruments with Xcode. Straight out of the gate, for some reason it's not profiling anything when using the Time Profiler.

I have cleaned my project, re-built, most of the obvious things, but I'm not having any luck still yet.

It runs the app, and the timer runs, but nothing happens beyond that. No stacks show up or any data of any kind. Just stays blank.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?

1. Start debugging your app with xcode in iOS simulator
2. Open instruments, then select iOS Simulator/CPU category and choose 'Time Profiler'
3. Change the Target combobox, All Process/Attach to Process
4. Look for your app in the displayed list and start record.

This image is an example, I'm attaching time profiler to my Calculator app:

[image: Attaching the time profiler to Calculator app in iOS simulator]

I hope this help you.

Comment: Yup, tried that and running directly from Instruments. No luck.

Comment: Can you verify that in cpu profiler, the target it is correctly set with your app?

Comment: Sorry, new to Instruments, how would I do this? I've had a poke around but not entirely sure what you mean.